# Go App Engine getting API error 7 (images: ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Seems that this would be from not loading the images service, but the module is loaded.  I do not get these errors on the development server.

I think the error is coming from this call `image.ServingURL(c, blobKey, nil)`, where the `blobKey` is

```
storageKey := r.FormValue("storageKey")
blobKey, err := blobstore.BlobKeyForFile(c, storageKey)
```

and the storage key is a key that represents a file in GSE.

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because the blobKey you have is referencing a Cloud Storage bucket that your app does not have access to.